# Looking for a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

For a didactic example Im looking for a differential equation with a specific form. We discuss two types of differential equations in class and the students should argue if this differential equation has the one form or the other. It would be nice if you know one which has actually both forms but is not obvious to see on the first look. Or having the one form but looks to be of the other form on the first look.

Riccati equation:

$y'(x) = P(x) [y(x)]^2 + Q(x)y(x) + R(x)$

Bernoulli equation:

$y'(x) = h(x)[y(x)]^a \ \ - g(x) y(x)$

Well I could go for $P(x) = h(x), \ a = 2, \ Q(x) = - g(x)$ and $R(x) = 0$.

Do you know a better one?

Comment: Do you mean Q(x) = -g(x)?

Comment: Yes. Let me edit that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly

the Jacobi differential equation:

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left[ (1-x)^{\alpha+1}(1+x)^{\beta+1} y'\right] +n(n+\alpha+\beta+1)(1-x)^{\alpha}(1+x)^{\beta}y=0
$$

and the Legendre differential equation

$$
(1-x^2)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-2x\frac{dy}{dx} +n(n+1)y=0
$$
appear at first glance to be unrelated, but are the same 
for $\alpha=\beta=0$